WMS layer doesn't load using PyQGIS
I'm using the following code to load a WMS layer to QGIS :
url = "https://data.geopf.fr/wms-r/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&STYLES=normal&FORMAT=image/geotiff&LAYERS=ELEVATION.ELEVATIONGRIDCOVERAGE.HIGHRES&CRS=EPSG:2154&WIDTH=2000&HEIGHT=2000&BBOX="
layer_name = "RGE ALTI"
provider = "wms"

layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('bbox')
layer = layers[0]
extent = layer.extent()
bbox_shp = f'{extent.xMinimum()},{extent.yMinimum()},{extent.xMaximum()},{extent.yMaximum()}'

 
url += bbox_shp

layer = QgsRasterLayer(url, layer_name, provider)


if layer.isValid():
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
    print("Layer added successfully!")

else:
    print("Failed to load layer.")

The layer doesn't load, but when I copy paste the url in a browser, I am able to download the corresponding layer. Anyone has had a similar problem ?
N.B : There is no problem with the bounding box shapefile
Edit: I've added the "url=" as mentioned in Loading WMS layer to QGIS using Python, however this does not fix the issue

2000 by 2000 is pretty big for a WMS image, maybe it's too big?

I'm not really familiar with adequate resolutions for WMS images, mind explaining?

check what the response from the server is - if it is xml then you need read the error and adjust accordingly. Does it work when you add it via the GUI?

I dont know how to check the server's response, is there a thread that shows how ? It works using the GUI, but only the png format is visible, when i choose tiff the layer is created but doesn't appear in the canvas.

but what is odd is that copy pasting this url : "https://data.geopf.fr/wms-r/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&STYLES=normal&FORMAT=image/geotiff&LAYERS=ELEVATION.ELEVATIONGRIDCOVERAGE.HIGHRES&CRS=EPSG:2154&WIDTH=1000&HEIGHT=1000&BBOX=644035.1470192916,6856896.960142511,659773.7940508621,6867627.855845855" directly on the browser makes it download the right layer

does QGIS support requesting the layer as tiff - try image/png

The GUI gives 3 possibilities : png, jpeg and tiff. Png and jpeg both work, but not tiff - i tried image/png and nothing changed, i dont think the issue is there because unlike with the GUI, using this code the layer does not even load

The layer will only show between defined scale limits <MinScaleDenominator>0.153269087</MinScaleDenominator> <MaxScaleDenominator>39.236886161</MaxScaleDenominator>

hi @nmtoken, i'm not sure i understand, mind explaining a bit more please?

see section 7.2.4.6.9 Scale denominators of the WMS standard ~ https://portal.ogc.org/files/?artifact_id=14416.   The service is declaring in the GetCapabilities response that the showing of the layer is restricted according to scale.  You influence scale of the returned image by specifying bounding box and image size

So all i need to do is to not specify bbox and image size?

update: not working when not specifying bbox and image size
