Display French survey DEM in QGIS
[QGIS 3.40, Windows 11, although I faced the same problem with many previous versions]
I'm trying to display -and use- the (otherwise excellent) DEM supplied by the French survey (IGN). My attempts so far resulted in partial success, and my interaction with the IGN staff suggests a problem from the QGIS side. Before filling in a bug report I'd like to explore if there is a solution that I may have overlooked or a workaround.
The WMS I want to display is located here: https://data.geopf.fr/annexes/ressources/wms-r/altimetrie.xml  (config XML), layer 5 "ELEVATION".
The following images are with an OSM image in the background, to demonstrate where we are. The projection is set to 2154 (French default).

Add the layer as a jpeg, EPSG:2154 (which the server says is served), i.e. the following GET:
https://data.geopf.fr/wms-r/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&BBOX=912239.7047890656395%2C6715938.366335349157%2C1114355.419687113026%2C6905202.793002884835&CRS=EPSG%3A2154&WIDTH=1038&HEIGHT=972&LAYERS=ELEVATION.ELEVATIONGRIDCOVERAGE.HIGHRES&STYLES=&FORMAT=image%2Fjpeg&DPI=96&MAP_RESOLUTION=96&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi%3A96


I get .. something. But
a) QGIS does not allow me to do anything with the symbology of this later (so no custom colour scale, no hillshade). "Single Band Colour data" is the only available option:

b) it is clear that the resulting image has been truncated to 255 (all the altitudes above 254 m in the Vosges are uniformly white). I cannot query the WMS layer (the query tool is inactive), but if I save a local copy I can see that I have values from 0 to 255.

Ok, so maybe the problem is because jpg stores only info on 8b. Let's try with a tiff and build the following request:

https://data.geopf.fr/wms-r/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&BBOX=912239.7047890656395%2C6715938.366335349157%2C1114355.419687113026%2C6905202.793002884835&CRS=EPSG%3A2154&WIDTH=1038&HEIGHT=972&LAYERS=ELEVATION.ELEVATIONGRIDCOVERAGE.HIGHRES&STYLES=&FORMAT=image%2Ftiff&DPI=96&MAP_RESOLUTION=96&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi%3A96&TRANSPARENT=TRUE

I see nothing at all. Even though the network inspector tells me that I'm downloading tiles (of size 612608).
Of course, I did notice that the request built by QGIS ends with "... TRANSPARENT=TRUE", but how can I change that?
Still no query tool, of course.
If I save the resulting layer as a tiff, I get an empty tiff (all pixels at zero).
The IGN staff assures me that they serve a well-conformed layer (I have no way to check, but I tend to trust them, historically they have demonstrated a remarkable proficiency with geomatics). Their analysis is that QGIS is incapable of displaying properly this data, in particular, because it disables all symbology options for WMS layers, and they suggest a workaround to save a local copy and work on it. Of course, I'd need to do this with the tiff (as jpg does not support 32b), except that the tiff does not seem to work here.
Question(s):

How can I display this layer in QGIS?
Ideally, I'd like to have actual control on it and be able to use regular symbology (hillshade)
Alternately I could live with saving a local copy and working on it...

Bonus question: is this a QGIS bug that needs to be reported, or a pilot error?

This might be related. Its the same WMS source:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/479715/wms-layer-doesnt-load-using-pyqgis

Adding the same layer in ArcGIS PRO give the same result (MNT display but no symbology option available and I can't query) so this is not a QGIS only problem...

Furthetmore, just open the Urls you provided as reference in a browser: similar issue... IGN folks should have a look again at what is actually served. Eh oui les gars!

So, after taking up the issue to QGIS side, there are some answers.

The jpg and png layers are served as 8 bit, which is clearly inadequate for a DEM (at the very least in France you need to code values up to 4807 m, the altitude of Mont-Blanc, and that's before we even start talking about decimals).  A bit pointless to serve DEMs in this format then, but harmless.
The tif layers are served as 32b (as they should) BUT QGIS built-in provider handles only 8-bit data. The QGIS developers seem to feel that this is a feature and not a bug, WMS being meant to serve rendered images and lacking the capacity to give clues about the nature (depth, color etc) of what they serve.
(have a look at the comments in the QGIS issue, here: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/59745 )

There is some hope however:

There is a more capable GDAL WMS driver that can read 32 bit images. One of the QGIS contributor kindly suggested that you can access it by building an xml file, as below, and add it as a raster layer. As a bonus, since it is now a raster, you can do all the normal symbology things:

  <Service name="WMS">
    <Version>1.3.0</Version>
    <ServerUrl>https://data.geopf.fr/wms-r/wms?SERVICE=WMS</ServerUrl>
    <Layers>ELEVATION.ELEVATIONGRIDCOVERAGE.HIGHRES</Layers>
    <CRS>IGNF:WGS84G</CRS>
    <ImageFormat>image/tiff</ImageFormat>
    <Transparent>FALSE</Transparent>
    <BBoxOrder>xyXY</BBoxOrder>
  </Service>
  <DataWindow>
    <UpperLeftX>-62.952807690</UpperLeftX>
    <UpperLeftY>51.105279680</UpperLeftY>
    <LowerRightX>45.304315330</LowerRightX>
    <LowerRightY>-13.007809420</LowerRightY>
    <SizeX>1073741824</SizeX>
    <SizeY>635901853</SizeY>
  </DataWindow>
  <BandsCount>1</BandsCount>
  <DataType>Float32</DataType>
  <BlockSizeX>1024</BlockSizeX>
  <BlockSizeY>1024</BlockSizeY>
  <OverviewCount>20</OverviewCount>
</GDAL_WMS>
(courtesy E. Rouault)

Adapt for your own needs.

There is another protocol, WCS, that is meant to serve non-rendered data (C is for "coverage") and should probably be used by IGN to serve such data.


The lack of control on symbology is discussed in the issue mentioned already, and also here: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/59131 . It is, however, a by-product of the above: QGIS built-in WMS driver expects rendered images and so "requires" no capacity to tweak symbology.

So apparently, the issue as it stands has a workaround, as described above; but no real fix because it seems that



IGN is not too likely to change their protocol and start serving their data as WCS;
QGIS is not likely to bend backwards to accommodate what they regard as an abuse of the WMS protocol by IGN.

